# Spring model to use multiple tables

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I got a database-table containing 50million+ rows. by indexing I reduced the request time for selecting a single row from 50sec to 2-5sec. Since I still need to retrieve multiple single rows. I was able to reduce even futher (<500ms) by performing the select on a view containing only records of the last month.
Unfortunately it is possible that a device didn't produce a record within the last month but I still need it's newest records.

Is there any possibility to tell spring mvc to "fallback" to another table, if there is no result on the primary table? something like:

```
@Entity
@Table
(
schema="tbl",
name="name_of_view_for_last_month",
fallbackname="name_of_actual_table"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  case check.exists
  when 1 then check.id 
  when 0 then (select id 
               from name_of_actual_table
               where <condition to get single row>)
  end as result
from (
    select count(id) as exist, id
    from name_of_view_for_last_month last
    where <condition to get single row>) check
```

what about solving it on SQL level like it's described above?

On Spring level you can create 2 dao classes for the full data table and for the month view.

In the service call the monthDataDao and if nothing is returned call the fullDataDao with the same request

Comment: thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. unfortunatly your code is not straight MySQL (or at least does not work in workbench), but i now got a good base to work on.